# sidewaysfigure error when adding a caption

Tags: errors, captions, rotating

I'm trying to include a uml diagram, which as it's quite large i'd like to rotate. However, if I try and add a caption I get an error and it won't build.

I'm adding the figure like this:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
...
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{clientUML.eps}
\label{fig:clientUML}
\caption{UML for client} 
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

And I get this error:

```
<clientUML.eps>
! Undefined control sequence.
\@tempf ... \@parboxrestore \normalsize \@fs@capt 
                                                  {\@nameuse {fnum@#1}}{\ign...
l.87 \caption{UML for client}
```

Any ideas? It works if I take the caption line out - but I need to include on.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I also have this in my preamble - I need boxes round my figures:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}
```

Comment: If I expand your code to a full, but minimal document it works fine for me. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the described behavior.  Most likely you are using a package which interferes somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you use `\restylefloat` in your preamble? If you omit this command, there will be no error.

Instead of using the `rotating` and the `float` package you can simply use the `rotfloat` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{test.jpg}
\label{fig:clientUML}
\caption{UML for client} 
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes - i've added the lines i'm using - I need boxes round my floats if possible.

Comment: @Freddie: I've updated my code.

Comment: great - that's sorted it. Thanks :)